# click event not fired in dynamically generated <li>

Tags: jquery, html, list, dynamic, click

hi all i am generating  my ul and li as follow and want to fire click event but delegate(),on()and click() method do not work  only live() works well but live() is deprecated function so is there any other method that i can use help me pls ??/
here **"loadpage"** is div present in my html code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#LoadPage').append('<ul class="testul" id="list">');
                 for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                   $('#list').append('<li class="clicks" id="item'+i+'"></li>');
                 }          
             $('#LoadPage').append('</ul>');
        });

            // click event works  wtih .live() onlyyy.......................
        $('.clicks').live('click', function() {
            alert('hello');
        });






        /*$(".clicks").on("click", function(){
            alert('hello');
        });
        $("#testul").delegate("li", "click", function() {
        alert('hello');
        });



        $("#testul").delegate("li", "click", function() {
            alert('hello');
              });*/

    </script>
```

Comment: why should you try with bind method?

Comment: because simple click is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector should match on document since document actually exists. You will then pass *on* the selector for clicks that will exist. By initially matching on .clicks, your result set is empty and nothing happens.

```
$(document).on("click", ".clicks", function(){ 
        alert('hello'); 
});
```

The documentation for *live* discusses how to convert code that uses it to use *on* or *delegate*: http://api.jquery.com/live/.

Answer (score 2):

hmmm..

i tried it with on and it worked well

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7dfSP/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The methods delegate(),on()and click() doesn't works because you are not loaded the html yet. Try to define it after you load the li elements.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#LoadPage').append('<ul class="testul" id="list">');
            for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
              $('#list').append('<li class="clicks" id="item'+i+'"></li>');
            }          
        $('#LoadPage').append('</ul>');
        $('.clicks').click(function() {
            alert('hello');
        });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#LoadPage').append('<ul class="testul" id="list">');
             for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
               $('#list').append('<li class="clicks" id="item'+i+'"></li>');
             }          
         $('#LoadPage').append('</ul>');
    });

        // click event works  wtih .live() onlyyy.......................
    $('.clicks').live('click', function() {
        alert('hello');
    });
```

Just change this to

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#LoadPage').append('<ul class="testul" id="list">');
             for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
               $('#list').append('<li class="clicks" id="item'+i+'"></li>');
             }          
         $('#LoadPage').append('</ul>');
         // click event works  wtih .live() onlyyy.......................
         $('.clicks').click(function() {
             alert('hello');
         });
    });
```

Previously those `<li>` items are not present in DOM, after inserting into DOM, it can have any functionality.

Comment: live work fine as i hv mentioned even if it is outside the loop ;but thanks i get new thing to learn  even that i have to use click event for all elements in loop ...:)

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated

What version of jQuery are you using? On has been added in version 1.7 look at the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

if you include the right version of jQuery it should work just fine.

and regarding delegate try this one [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bWb77/1/)

Comment: do you get any errors in your console? because on should work fine